# How to change format / treat missing values in SPSS

Tags: spss, missing-data, spss-modeler

I'm using `SPSS modeler` and I have a variable that the software recognizes as numeric. So the `missing` values are `$null$`. I want that the missing values of the variable are selectionable with `''`, as `character`.

So I would: or trasform the format of the variable from `numeric` to `character` or change only the `missing` values from `$null$` to `''`.

How can I fix?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to select null values in a numeric field is to use the @NULL() function from the Blanks and Null section of the Expression Builder.

For example, if you wanted to keep only the null values so that you could inspect them, you might use a Select node. Leave the radio button set as Include. Press the Expression Builder (calculator) button. Change the filter in the drop menu on the left side from General Functions to show Blanks and Null (press B 2 or 3 times). Double-click on @NULL(ITEM). Go to the right side and double-click on your numeric field name. Put a Table node at the end and run it.

[Using Select @NULL in IBM SPSS Modeler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy56H.png)

Another way to view just the null rows is to enter the @NULL(varname) function into the "Highlight records where" section of the Table dialog box.

["Highlight records where" dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVGzn.png)

When you run the table, any row that is true for this condition will be shown in red.

If you really need the variable to be a string, then use a Compute node to create a copy of this field under a new name and use the to_string() function in the Conversion section of the Expression Builder to change the type of the variable. Now you will be able to use the the Select node to grab "" as the missing value. Or you could use the Filler node to replace the column, but then you would not be able to compare before and after.

The dialog examples shown in this answer use this sample stream that is installed with your IBM SPSS Modeler software:

C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Modeler\18.0\Demos\streams\featureselection.str

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it it's using the Fill node with the configurations:

A) FIELD

B) Condition = **@NULL(@FIELD)**

C) Replace by = **' '**

This node will replace all $null$ for ' ' at the same variable chosen in option a.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can customize how you visualize $nulls. (I know it's possible in SQL db though)
So I'd suggest that you work with the numbers and when you want to visualize or export the results, then turn the field to a string one then replace nulls:
 Filled node > to_string(@FIELD)
 Filler node > blank and nulls > @FIELD = ''